# Change profile attached email address

Tags: azure-devops

I was recently given access to a private Pipelines project via a particular email address that is associated with my Github account. When I went to Azure's site I hit "sign up with Github" since this was convenient. Instead of using the email I have access on, which is my primary email on Github, but listed second in the list of emails; it used my non-primary email that was listed first on the emails list. I'd rather not use it for Azure.

I can't seem to figure out how to change the email associated with the account, just the "contact" email, or even just delete the account and try again. I have nothing on here, I just need an azure account with the correct email address to access this singular private Pipelines project.

This is probably not the venue for this type of question, and I apologize for that, but Azure's support services are non-existent or require a paid subscription.

[image]

I want the profile email (currently ktbarret.connectflour@gmail.com) to be what my contant email is.

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let us know if you would like further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

> Change profile attached email address

I am there is no such a way to change the profile attached email address.

That because this account is the account added by the pipeline administrator when you are invited to access this private pipeline. **The owner of the invited account does not have permission to modify the account**, otherwise we can use this method to allow an unauthorized account to access the private pipeline without the consent of the administrator of the private pipeline. Obviously this is extremely dangerous.

To resolve this issue, you have to contact the admin of that private pipeline to **remove the currently account from the Users and add your contact email to the organization where the private pipeline is located.** Then you can access that private pipeline with the contact email account. The profile email will be your contact email.

On the other hand, if the contact email could not access your github directly, you could add it as collaborator, so that you could use that account to sign up github.

Hope this helps.